# custom password digest issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to add hashed custom password into User model. What I did is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :check_domain

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:slug, :custom_password_digest])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:slug, :custom_password_digest])
    end

end
```

new.html

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :slug %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :slug %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :custom_password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :custom_password %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

class User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_secure_password :custom_password
  validates :slug, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

I am getting error now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILHjc.png

[image]

Could you please advise me what i am doing wrong?

Purpose is to save hashed custom_password to User table.

Comment: You need to explain what error you're seeing.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn added screenshot. Can you please help?

Comment: Answer below! Post another question if you have further problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the field to store your encrypted password.

Create a migration to add it to the database...

```
rails g migration AddCustomPasswordDigestToUser custom_password_digest:string
```

then run the migration...

```
rails db:migrate
```